# reading columns from a txt file

Tags: c, file, getline

i have a txt file that has 5 columns like in the image below, and i want to store each one of those values, like for example to have an array that contains the values in the first column, another array for the values of the second column and so on.
i managed to read the first column using the following code, but i'm not sure how to read the others.
Thanks in advance.

```
int main() {
char *value=NULL;
double Training[401], Test[50];
int i=0, j=0;
double newvalue;
double line;
double *a=NULL;
double val1[10], val2[10], val3[10], val4[10];
size_t line_buf_size = 0;

FILE *in_file  = fopen("turbine.txt", "r");
        if (in_file == NULL)
        {
          printf("Error! Could not open file\n");
          exit(-1);
        }

        while(i<4) // reading the first 4 values of the first column , works well 
        {
            getline(&value, &line_buf_size, in_file);
            fscanf(in_file,"%s%*[^\n]",value);
            sscanf(value, "%lf", &newvalue);
            Training[i]=newvalue;
            i++;
        }

        while (j<4) // this is my attempt to read 4 columns, didn't want to run the code for the whole file so i'm just testing in it on 4 lines, no results and no error
            {
                    //line=getline(&a, &line_buf_size, in_file);
                    //fscanf(in_file, "%s", a);
                    scanf (in_file, "%lf %lf %lf %lf %lf ", &val1[0], &val2[1], &val3[2], &val4[3]);
                    printf("The values are: %lf %lf %lf %lf\n", val1, val2, val3, val4);
                j++;
            }

fclose (in_file);
return 0;    }
```

[txt file image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFErB.png)

Comment: Could you share file contexts as text rather than image?

Comment: Don't post pictures of text. Is making a screenshot, trimming it, saving the picture, and uploading it is really easier than just copy/pasting the text?

Comment: @RohanKumar  sorry, i just wanted to give u an idea, and i didn't want my post to be long.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to do it like this:

```c
char line[100];
int nLines = 0;
while (fgets(line, 100, in_file)) {
    sscanf(line, "%lf%lf%lf%lf%lf", &val1[nLines], &val2[nLines], &val3[nLines], &val4[nLines], &val5[nLines]);
    nLines++;
}

for (int i = 0; i < nLines; i++) {
    printf("%lf %lf %lf %lf %lf\n",  val1[i], val2[i], val3[i], val4[i], val5[i]);
}
```

I tested this on my own version of test file:

```
1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0
6.0 7.0 8.0 11.0 9.0
11.0 23.04 34.1 34.1 45.0
```

when I ran this program with this file, I was able to see desired input:

```
c-posts : $ gvim readingColumns.c 
c-posts : $ cat turbine.txt 
1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0
6.0 7.0 8.0 11.0 9.0
11.0 23.04 34.1 34.1 45.0
c-posts : $ gcc readingColumns.c 
c-posts : $ ./a.out 
1.000000 2.000000 3.000000 4.000000 5.000000
6.000000 7.000000 8.000000 11.000000 9.000000
11.000000 23.040000 34.100000 34.100000 45.000000
```

Comment: it kinda works, i have some results but it's like the values printed are selected randomly from the file, and it just outputs 10 lines, how can i do it for the whole file ?

Comment: Oh, is it? Could you please share your file so that I can test it out?

Comment: here you go : https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1HcsN3TrnosAVWhdbLSFPL0TF1D2E9_lA

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I got sick a few days ago. When I'm opening your link I'm getting Unauthorized

Comment: it's okay i did it in other way, thanks for your help.